# Delete data in table row?

Tags: google-app-maker

How can I add trash icon next to data row to delete that (row) value from datasource?

I have data rows: @datasource.item.Type @datasource.item.Color and @datasource.item.Item
There are some drop down values for those items, e.g. blue, red etc.
No allowNull value is available in the drop down, but I would like to be able to delete data in that row.

Comment: Generally when you drag a table widget into your canvas and set a datasource the next choice is which fields to include in the table and then the next choice is a group of three checkboxes one says 'Deleteable Rows'. Make sure that checkbox is checked and it will automatically create a delete item button for you.

Comment: That would delete the entire record row. I need to delete datasource.item (e.g.  @datasource.item.Type) which is listed in columns.

Comment: Interesting setup. Let’s say you ‘delete’ each item, then you would still remain with a record though just without any values, i.e. all null values. Is this datasource just made up of a single record (item)? Because all you can really do here is set the value of the item columns equal to null, rather than actually deleting it. The way to do this is for each column what you are calling a row add a button and add @datasource.item.YourColumn = null.